# Unable to generate tables with eclipse link and oracle db - IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I've created a dynamic web project and added JPA facet in my eclipse mars.
In my build path, I have: jdk8, EclipseLink 2.6, JPA 2.1, Tomcat 8, Oracle thin driver(ojdbc14.jar);

There is a strange matter because the same project works in some machines but doesn't work in others.

For the purpose I think that tomcat is not essential because I just want generate tables from entities in a simple jpa project.

I've created two jpa entities and I've set `persistence.xml` to point to my Oracle database (Ping successful):

```
persistence.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="question" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>it.corsojava.question.domain.Student</class>
        <class>it.corsojava.question.domain.Question</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.14.111:1521:ORCL"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="fede"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="fede"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.is-lazy" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.mode" value="Transactional"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="Oracle-JDBC"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Question.java
    package it.corsojava.question.domain;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.Long;
import java.lang.String;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Question
 *
 */
@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Question() {
        super();
    }   
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

Student.java

```
package it.corsojava.question.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.Long;
import java.lang.String;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Student
 *
 */
@Entity 
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Student() {
        super();
    }   
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }   
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }   
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, when I run JPA tools>create tables from entities... I get following error:

```
[EL Fine]: server: Configured server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform
[EL Config]: metadata: The access type for the persistent class [class it.corsojava.question.domain.Question] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: metadata: The access type for the persistent class [class it.corsojava.question.domain.Student] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: metadata: The alias name for the entity class [class it.corsojava.question.domain.Question] is being defaulted to: Question.
[EL Config]: metadata: The table name for entity [class it.corsojava.question.domain.Question] is being defaulted to: QUESTION.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [id] is being defaulted to: ID.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [text] is being defaulted to: TEXT.
[EL Config]: metadata: The alias name for the entity class [class it.corsojava.question.domain.Student] is being defaulted to: Student.
[EL Config]: metadata: The table name for entity [class it.corsojava.question.domain.Student] is being defaulted to: STUDENT.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [password] is being defaulted to: PASSWORD.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [name] is being defaulted to: NAME.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [id] is being defaulted to: ID.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [email] is being defaulted to: EMAIL.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [username] is being defaulted to: USERNAME.
[EL Severe]: ejb: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.errorDecryptingPassword(ValidationException.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateLogins(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2404)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2716)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.buildEntityManagerFactory(Main.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:68)
Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:913)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DESCipher.java:314)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:109)
    ... 12 more

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.buildEntityManagerFactory(Main.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:68)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.errorDecryptingPassword(ValidationException.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateLogins(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2404)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2716)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:710)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:913)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DESCipher.java:314)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:109)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relates to a known [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512344) which was fixed with version *2.6.5-RC1*. It also works as expected with the latest **2.6.5-RC2** release candidate (available since June 2017).

In case you have a Maven project, change the version string of the *EclipseLink* dependency like so:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
     <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
     <version>2.6.5-RC2</version>
 </dependency>
```

If this is a standalone project, find the latest [2.6.5-RC2 jar file on Maven Central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.6.5-RC2/eclipselink-2.6.5-RC2.jar). Just remove the old *jar* file and put the new one in the application's class path.

Hope it helps.